# BigQuery is deleting lines in my script when I only run part of it

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a moderately complex script (create about 20 different tables, approx 1500 lines). When making changes, I only need to run the part of the code that comes after the change. I normally dont have any issues with this, but today, I selected lines 800-1500, hit ctrl + enter, and when it completed the run 6 minutes later, I found that all of the code above the line I started the run from (ie lines 1-799) had been deleted.

When I hit ctrl+z nothing happens, so somehow the change has been locked in. I have some earlier versions of the script, but there are changes in here that got deleted that I dont have saved anywhere else.

Two questions:

1. why is this happening? any way to prevent it from happening again? (other than stricter version control, or running the subset of the query in another query editing window)
2. Any way to recover the deleted code if ctrl+z doesnt work, and it's not in the query history as I didnt run that piece of it today?

notes: using BigQuery web interface for this

Comment: I've recently started to see this issue repeatedly the last month, never has been happening before. Critical problem as it overwrites saved query script

Comment: Hi, I work on this team, is this still an issue?

Answer (score 2):

Something caused your browser tab to reload itself. The URL in the browser immediately updates itself with a new `job_id` parameter every time you execute a query, and going to that URL (via reloading the tab or otherwise) will display the exact SQL executed by that job and the resultset if the job has finished. If you've only highlighted a portion of the query -- welp, that's the query that got run so that's the query that will be displayed when you revisit that url. :(

The new "editor tabs" feature has been causing this for me: I have to click the "disable editor tabs" button at the top of the bigquery UI to prevent the page from reloading when running queries with multiple stages. But there are an endless number of possible reasons that your particular tabs might be reloading on your particular system, so here's a second fix:

Use `/* */` SQL comments to block off the parts of the query that you don't want to run. The comments are part of your query and will therefore still be visible even if the browser tab reloads.

Comment: Going to try "disable editor tabs" too to see if this fixes the issue

Comment: Hi, I work on this team, is this still an issue?